# Plan to make a SO indicator for Firefox

Tags: firefox, shared-libraries

**Problem:** to show that a Not-SO-page has been discussed in SO when you at the Not-SO-site by a SO indicator at Firefox bottom bar

**How should the extension work?**

It should show a colorful SO indicator if the not-SO-page has been at SO.

I assume that we cannot use

- Google *(because the addon is apparently against its TOS)*
- SO has no similar search as the following Google search

**The Google search which we are not allowed to use**

```
site:url_in_firefox
```

**Is there any to see whether the Not-SO-page has been discussed elsewhere or not?**

Comment: I disagree. It's no clearer than before.

Comment: @John: 2nd try: it should now be clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out these tutorials at David Walsh's blog:

- [Firefox Extension Template](http://davidwalsh.name/firefox-extension-template)
- [Package Your Firefox Extension into an XPI](http://davidwalsh.name/package-xpi-zip)
- [Adding the XPI MIME Type for Firefox Extension Installs](http://davidwalsh.name/xpi-mime) – if you want to make users able to install your add-on from your server and not the official add-on repository

Comment: Thank you for the links! --- Do you see whether it is possible to build such an addon. --- If we cannot use Google or SO's similar search (IF there is one), we cannot build the extension.

Comment: I suppose it would be possible, since Firefox extensions uses JavaScript. You could try using JSONP and request data from Google, Yahoo, or perhaps SO itself. However, I'm not sure if any of these allows this – you'll have to check with them.